# UITableViewDiffableDataSource's defaultRowAnimation is not working

Tags: ios

According to Apple's [defaultRowAnimation | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource/3255148-defaultrowanimation):

> If you set the value of this property, the new value becomes the default row animation for the next update that uses apply(_:animatingDifferences:completion:).

My Code:

```swift
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
  var diff = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, Document>()
    
  snapshot.sectionIdentifiers.forEach{ section in
    diff.appendSections([section as! String])
      
    let items = snapshot.itemIdentifiersInSection(withIdentifier: section).map{
      (objectId: Any) -> Document in
      let oid = objectId as! NSManagedObjectID
      return controller.managedObjectContext.object(with: oid) as! Document
    }
      
    diff.appendItems(items, toSection: section as? String)
  }
  self.dataSource?.defaultRowAnimation = .fade
  self.dataSource?.apply(diff, animatingDifferences: tableView.window != nil)
}
```

`self.dataSource` is an instance of class `FileListDataSource`, whose definition is

```swift
class FileListDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<String, Document> {
  
  weak var delegate: UITableViewDataSource?
  
  
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if (delegate != nil) {
      return delegate?.tableView?(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

No matter what `defaultRowAnimation` was set, the deletion animation was the same.

Comment: Unrelated but why do you create a new snapshot from the `snapshot` parameter rather than applying the `snapshot` parameter directly? `self.dataSource?.apply(snapshot as NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, NSManagedObjectID>, animatingDifferences: tableView.window != nil)`

Comment: @vadian I think it's because they are different types. `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, Document>` and `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, NSManagedObjectID>`. So manual type conversion is involved. Maybe there are better ways to do it since I started iOS development only a couple months ago.

Comment: The different type doesn't matter. The data source can handle also `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, NSManagedObjectID>`.